# Save id anchor href when changing page language

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the case. I have a page, on which I have several options to choose. Choice is being made by clicking a link, which leads to an anchor and displays necessary content. Unfortunately this could not be changed. The problem is, that I also have a language panel, which leads me to the same page but already translated to necessary locale. My goal is to be able change language, but also save the chosen anchor from a clicked link. Was not able to find solution yet, could someone please give any idea, how that could be done?
Here is link to a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/william_eduards/psuLrv02/87/

```js
let contents = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.content'));
let contentOne = document.querySelector('.content--a');
let contentTwo = document.querySelector('.content--b');

const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  contents.forEach(node => {
    node.classList.remove('active');
  });
  e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
    if (document.querySelector('.content-a').classList.contains('active')) {
    contentOne.classList.add('show');
  } else {
    contentOne.classList.remove('show');
  }

  if (document.querySelector('.content-b').classList.contains('active')) {
    contentTwo.classList.add('show');
  } else {
    contentTwo.classList.remove('show');
  }
}

contents.forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});
```

```css
.content--a, .content--b {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="select-option">
    <a class="content content-a" href="#contentA">Content A</a>
    <a class="content content-b" href="#contentB">Content b</a>
 </div>
 <div class="options">
   <div class="content--a" id="contentA">
    <p>I am content a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content--b" id="contentB">
    <p>I am content b</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To show your contents, just use CSS with pseudo class `:target` (remove all your js)

```css
.content--a, .content--b {
  display: none;
}
.options > *:target {
  display: block;
}
```

2. If your page is reloaded when you select language, use sessionStorage to remember which link was last clicked, and restore it on next page load. Following code assumes the URL is unchanged when you switch languages:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {

  const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
  //Save selection on click as url#anchor
  contents.forEach(node => {
    node.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const href = node.getAttribute('href');
      console.log(href);
      if (href) {
        const spl = href.split('#');
        if (spl.length > 1 && spl[1].length) {
          const spl2 = window.location.href.split('#');
          sessionStorage.setItem('shown-content', spl2[0] + '#' + spl[1]);
          console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('shown-content'));
        }
      }
    });
  });
  
  //Restore selection on load if URL is the same up until anchor
  const anch = sessionStorage.getItem('shown-content');
  if (anch) {
    const spl = anch.split('#');
    if (spl.length) {
      const spl2 = window.location.href.split('#');
      console.log(spl[0], spl2[0]);
      if (spl[0] == spl2[0])
        window.location.href = anch;
    }
  }
});
```

3. Adapt above code to your needs if URL changes between languages

**Full example** *(doesn't run as a snippet. Use server or local html file)*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    
    <style>
      .content--a, .content--b {
        display: none;
      }
      .options > *:target {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
        const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

        //Save selection on click as url#anchor
        contents.forEach(node => {
          node.addEventListener('click', e => {
            const href = node.getAttribute('href');
            console.log(href);
            if (href) {
              const spl = href.split('#');
              if (spl.length > 1 && spl[1].length) {
                const spl2 = window.location.href.split('#');
                sessionStorage.setItem('shown-content', spl2[0] + '#' + spl[1]);
                console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('shown-content'));
              }
            }
          });
        });

        //Restore selection on load if URL is the same up until anchor
        const anch = sessionStorage.getItem('shown-content');
        if (anch) {
          const spl = anch.split('#');
          if (spl.length) {
            const spl2 = window.location.href.split('#');
            console.log(spl[0], spl2[0]);
            if (spl[0] == spl2[0])
              window.location.href = anch;
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="languages">
        <a href="">English</a>
        <a href="">Français</a>
      </div>
      <div class="select-option">
        <a class="content content-a" href="#contentA">Content A</a>
        <a class="content content-b" href="#contentB">Content b</a>
      </div>
      <div class="options">
        <div class="content--a" id="contentA">
          <p>I am content a</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content--b" id="contentB">
          <p>I am content b</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save the element which is active. No big deal.

```
let contents = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.content'));
...
let activeEl = null;

const handleClick = (e) => {
  ...
  e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  activeEl = e.currentTarget; // adding the `<a/>` tag in a global 
  ...
}
```